# What is the difference between AddHandler and AddType in htaccess files

Tags: .htaccess, addhandler

Can someone explain what the difference is between AddType and AddHandler in htaccess files? I want to make the settings such that I can have a javascript file (.js) be run through the server as though it were a php file (application/x-httpd-php5) but then sent to the user's browser as a (text/javascript) file. How might i configure this?

Comment: 'I want to make the settings such that I can have a javascript file (.js) be run through the server as though it were a php file (application/x-httpd-php5) but then sent to the user's browser as a (text/javascript) file.' Why on earth would you want to do that?!?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doesn't sound like a great idea to parse all .js files as php.  I would suggest using a .htaccess Rewrite directive to map the .js files in question, to your php script.

```
RewriteRule /phpjs/.* /phpjs/js.php
```

Then add

```
header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
```

to your php output.

Answer (score 7):

AddHandler http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler tells the server how to handle the file type. AddType http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype tells the server what MIME type to give the client.